# Check if Node exists for given UUID

Tags: java, freemarker, uuid, jcr, magnolia

**Context:** I am running **Magnolia CMS 5.x** & try to programmatically (in `freemarker`) check if a node exist to avoid getting an exception thrown when trying to access it via `${damfn.getAssetLink(<someUUID>)}` or similar.

---

Is there a way to check if a Node with a given UUID exist?

I found nothing interesting when looking at [NodeUtil.java](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/users/ejervidalo/repos/main/browse/magnolia-core/src/main/java/info/magnolia/jcr/util/NodeUtil.java), [SessionUtil.java](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/users/ejervidalo/repos/main/browse/magnolia-core/src/main/java/info/magnolia/jcr/util/SessionUtil.java), [Session.java](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html), [JCRUtils](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html), [TemplatingFunction (`cmsfn:`)](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.5/apidocs/info/magnolia/templating/functions/TemplatingFunctions.html) & DamTemplatingFunctions (`damfn:`)

I only could find that you can check via path using [jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/Checking-if-node-exists-td516003.html](http://jackrabbit.510166.n4.nabble.com/Checking-if-node-exists-td516003.html)

---

#### Resources:

- [Node.java - API doc - *Adobe's Content Repository for Java 2.0*](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html)
- [Session.java - API doc - *Adobe's Content Repository for Java 2.0*](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/spec/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Session.html)
- [JCRUtils.java - API doc - Apache Jackrabbit 2.0.0 API](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/2.0/org/apache/jackrabbit/commons/JcrUtils.html)
- [NodeUtil.java - code - *Magnolia Main Project*](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/users/ejervidalo/repos/main/browse/magnolia-core/src/main/java/info/magnolia/jcr/util/NodeUtil.java)
- [NodeUtil.java - API doc - *Magnolia Main Project 5.5*](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.5/apidocs/info/magnolia/jcr/util/NodeUtil.html)
- [SessionUtil.java - code - *Magnolia Main Project*](https://git.magnolia-cms.com/users/ejervidalo/repos/main/browse/magnolia-core/src/main/java/info/magnolia/jcr/util/SessionUtil.java)
- [SessionUtil.java - API doc - *Magnolia Main Project 5.5*](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.5/apidocs/info/magnolia/jcr/util/SessionUtil.html)
- [`TemplatingFunction.java` (`cmsfn:`) *explained by Magnolia CMS' team*](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/cmsfn)
- [`DamTemplatingFunctions.java` (`damfn:`) *explained by Magnolia CMS' team*](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/damfn)
- [`DamTemplatingFunctions.java` code](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/modules/magnolia-dam-templating/2.0.2/magnolia-dam-parent/magnolia-dam-templating/xref/info/magnolia/dam/templating/functions/DamTemplatingFunctions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(See my update below for a simple solution using standard Magnolia directives)*

How about using the search `searchfn`

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/searchfn

or `QueryUtil`

https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.4/apidocs/info/magnolia/cms/util/QueryUtil.html

and searching by UUID:

https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/JCR+Query+Cheat+Sheet

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] WHERE [jcr:uuid] = '7fd401be-cada-4634-93fa-88069f46297b'
```

---

**Using it in Freemarker:**

You can wrap every Java function, such as search, in a custom freemarker directive.

See [documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Templating+functions](http://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Templating+functions)

In your module xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module SYSTEM "module.dtd" >
<module>
  ...
  <components>
    <id>main</id>
    <component>
      <type>com.company.my.MyTemplatingFunctions</type>
      <implementation>com.company.my.MyTemplatingFunctions</implementation>
      <scope>singleton</scope>
    </component>  
  </components>
...
```

`com.company.my.MyTemplatingFunctions.doesNodeExist()` calls the `QueryUtil` standard class - or `SessionUtil` such as:

```
package com.company.my;

public class MyTemplatingFunctions {
    public boolean doesNodeExist(String workspace, String id){
        if ( SessionUtil.getNodeByIdentifier(workspace, id) != null ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then in your `.ftl`:

```
[#-- @ftlvariable name="myfn" type="com.company.my.MyTemplatingFunctions" --]
${myfn.doesNodeExist(relevantWorkspace, someUUID)}
```

---

**== Update ==**

Just checking the Magnolia docs:

https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/damfn#damfn-Getasset

Does this not work?

```
[#assign myAsset = damfn.getAsset("jcr:20d6e4e3-fe53-4b23-8d64-6e67a1c1667f")!]
```

where you can then check with `if` / `else` in Freemarker for `myAsset`?

This would look like the simplest solution. Haven't tested it but it looks as if it should be possible to pass the UUID together with the `jcr:` prefix.

Furthermore: if you don't need to explicitly check if the asset exists, but just don't want to get a template error in the log, you can add a `!` like this:

```
${damfn.getAssetLink(<someUUID>)!}
```

then you don't get a template error, just a WARN message in the log.

Comment: Thank Mathias. I have clarified the question to indicate that I want to do this in freemarker. Maybe you can add freemarker examples for each solution you suggest?

Comment: Note: `searchfn` requires the [MTE module](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/MTE+module) as shown in the "Function sets" table of the [Templating functions Magnolia doc](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Templating+functions).

Comment: See my updated reply. About MTE: are you not using MTE? MTE is the standard in the current 5.x, while STK is "deprecated". Or do you not want to rely on any of these template engines at all? Above should work without MTE, but it requires your own custom Java class for the custom directive.

Comment: @AdrienBe See my second update. There is even an easier way using the `damfn` directive. `damfn:getAsset('jcr:'+uuid)` and then use `if` and `else`.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer and comments. Well spotted, didn't see that [`damfn.getAsset(String UUID)`](https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/modules/magnolia-dam-templating/2.0.2/magnolia-dam-parent/magnolia-dam-templating/xref/info/magnolia/dam/templating/functions/DamTemplatingFunctions.html#104) returns null if the asset does not exist (vs throwing an error). The solution using a custom freemarker directive is pretty neat otherwise. For the `!` solution: can this "reduce" the log level for any exception? or only for exceptions thrown from specific methods?